# iOS camera UIView overlay full screen on iPad?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm trying to make an overlay on the camera mode on iPad. when the camera is in landscape mode, the overlay only covers 2/3 of the screen instead of the full screen.  It is covering the whole screen in portrait mode however. My guess is the overlay could possibly be only showing in portrait size so that the overlay doesn't appear to be covering the full screen.

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
overlay.alpha = 0.3; 
overlay.opaque = NO;

imagePicker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes;
imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;


imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;
```

However can i make it to cover the whole screen? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: put nslog for [[uiscreen mainscreen]bounds] an check its size ie width and height does it shows landscap size ? As i know and i face my development time it stays or return portrait all the time

Comment: and if it shows portrait size all the time just use manual settings like `CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);` assuming that you need full screen covered with it you can change it as according to your requirement

Comment: hmmm... it returns null.

Comment: so use manual method as i have sait in my second comment

Comment: it doesn't work on the portrait mode though, should there be like a rotation if statement with CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024); ?

Comment: yes it is required to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do manual setting for view frame. when it rotate to Portrait or Landscape.

For Portrait 
CGRectMake(0,0,768,1024);

For Landscape
CGRectMake(0,0,1024,768);

Comment: how would you write that statement though?  if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) above the CGRectMake?

Comment: Create UIView object as class object. and when your app rotate you will get response in 
"- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation"
here you can check the orientation and set View fram according to the orientation

Comment: Hardcoding anything is a quite bad idea. You can resize by [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size or anything else.