# how to start camera view full screen on an iOS app?

Tags: html, objective-c

I would like to call the camera to open full screen view on the iOS what function do i use for iPhone? Also how do i call compass to  be drawn on top of the iOS camera view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this below link may help you.let me know if is working or not..!!!!

Happy Coding!!!!!!

[iOS camera UIView overlay full screen on iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448631/ios-camera-uiview-overlay-full-screen-on-ipad)

Comment: thank you i had another question do you know how to print a matrix in GUI for java eclipse?

Comment: i am not getting your question , can you elaborate me please?

Comment: i created and printed a matrix in the console in eclipse using the language java. I would like to create a GUI. I want the matrix to print in the GUI instead of the console. Using java, and the IDE eclipse. Thank you so much for your help.